# Android studio can not recognise an old version of gradle file

Tags: android, gradle, android-recyclerview, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I am trying to open a project i created and developed long time ago using android studio. but every time i try to open and run the project i receive the following errors. that project was working normally without any errors in gradle files.
please let me know how to fix it

**error**:

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1
Add Google Maven repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1
Add Google Maven repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0
Add Google Maven repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
Affected Modules: app


WARNING: Configuration 'testCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
Affected Modules: app


WARNING: Configuration 'androidTestCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'androidTestImplementation'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
Affected Modules: app


WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.3.2.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
Remove Build Tools version and sync project
Affected Modules: app
```

**gradle project**:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        maven {
            url 'https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo'

        }
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**gradle app**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.pc_amr.retrofit_3"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.solidfire.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson-parent:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.solidfire.code.gson:gson-parent:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maven repository is missing, so do it as follows, in porject level `gradle` file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, you must instead use:
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        // An alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'

       jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but now after the maven repo is added, i receive the foolowing: "connection reset", "sync failed" and I canot use RecycleViewer" any class contains RecycleViewer object is highlighted with red as an error.pls help me to fix it